# After deleting a control, should not be select another control (C# Window Application )

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, c#-3.0

The current behavior is that when there is more than one control on a page and you delete a control, the application will select the next control or in the case of only one control on the page the application will select the TABGPAGE control (page/canvas). The desired behavior is that after a delete action no control will be selected.

For Example in C# window application if i have 3 controls and i delete 3rd control then it automatically focus on 2nd control 
but my customer  want to do not focus any other control after deleting control.
how can do this?

Comment: These aren't really great ideas, so I will put them as a comment instead of an answer. You could try setting the focus to a different control using `ctrl.Focus();` (you could focus on a panel or something so the focus isn't noticeable) or you could **try** setting `ctrl.TabStop = false;` on the controls you don't want to focus on (not certain if this will work). Keep in mind that setting TabStop to false will remove the user's ability to Tab through the controls. Personally, I would try to find a way to make the first suggestion work. Just focus on something that's not noticeable.

Comment: [I found this explanation of these options.](http://goo.gl/pXNcxl)